# Given a deep-link to a live-feed stream, how can I display this livestream within my app in iOS?

Tags: ios, swift, deep-linking, nest-api

I'm currently working with the NEST Camera and was wondering how I could display the live feed within my app. They give me an app deep link but I'm not quite sure what to do with it. It's format is "nestmobile://cameras/agioerjgoiar.....".

Answer (score 0):

Deeplinks are to send a user to a specific instance in another app. You cannot "pull" in video from the Nest app into your app.

Answer (score 0):

The app_url is used to launch Nest app. I believe you can use the web_url and host with WKWebView within your iOS app.

```
/**
 * Returns a web URL (deep link) to the live camera feed at home.nest.com.
 *
 * @return A web URL (deep link) to the live camera feed at home.nest.com.
 */
@JsonGetter(KEY_WEB_URL)
public String getWebUrl() {
    return mWebUrl;
}
```